# Android App problems bringing right main activity to front

Tags: android

In my project I am trying to bring my application to front after app is finished (User pressed back button). But it only gives me the last opened app to front. So if I am using a different app in the mean time it will open this app and not my app. Maybe some one can help me - I tried a lot of different combinations with Flags, but it didn't work. Additionally I didn't found a solution to get my app back if the display is locked - Maybe someone has a good solution for that or can give me advice.
Thanks

```
public class IncomingBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    MyActivity myActivity = (MyActivity) context;
    myActivity.doWork();
}

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
private boolean appInBackground = false;
...
@Override
public void onStop() {
    appInBackground = true;
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void finish() {
    if (exitPressed) {
        super.finish();
    } else {
        appInBackground = true;
        moveTaskToBack(false);
    }
}

public void doWork() {
// bring app to foreground
if (appInBackground) {
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyActivity.class);
    intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent1);
}
....
}
```

}

Android Manifest launchMode: android:launchMode="singleTask"

UPDATE:
I used my app to indicate incoming SIP calls, I had a look at the demo application for WalkieTalkieActivity (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SipDemo)

```
    // main Activity
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
        callReceiver = new IncomingBroadcastReceiver ();
        this.registerReceiver(callReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                    "com.example.INCOMING"));
    ...
            // me = SipProfile
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setAction("com.example.INCOMING");
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0,
                    i, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
            manager.open(me, pi, null);
    }
```

EXAMPLE:
My app is in foreground and I press back button to take it to back. Then I open another app for example hangouts, than I press the home button to go back to main screen. If the broadcast receiver gets an incoming call "INCOMING" than my app should appear, but it opens hangouts.

Comment: Can you explain what is your IncomingBroadcastReceiver  listening to? I mean for which intent. And Also can you explain your problem with example as I am not able to understand your problem completely.

Comment: Hello - see my update, additionally the doWork() function will be called, without any troubles..

Comment: so your intent was not proper? I have not gone through the link you shared but can you tell what was your problem

Answer (score 0):

> My app is in foreground and I press back button

When you press back button, the current activity instance is lost.hence the value of appInBackground set in

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    appInBackground = true;
    super.onStop();
}
```

is lost too.

so next time when you receive the broadcast and arrive at `public void doWork()`, appInBackground  is null.

Comment: Hello thanks for the hint, but this is actually not true. AppInBackground in my doWork is true and not null, so the program jumps into the intent case.

Comment: have you tied renaming MyActivity to somethin else?

Comment: I can try, but why should this make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Now I have found a solution: I should take the pendingIntent in my doWork() method and send it. Now my app is taking to front, even if it wasn't the last opened app. Thanks for the hints, now I have to work on bringing my app to front if screenlock is enabled. Any ideas?

```
public void doWork() {
    // bring app to foreground
    if (appInBackground) {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent();
        intent1.setClass(getBaseContext(),MyActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, intent1,   PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        pendingIntent.send();
    }
...
}
```